# What are these called in english?

Tags: baking, cake, language

I'm looking for the names of "Rollfondant" and "Modellierfondant" in english. 
I'm new to the *métier* but as far as I can tell, Rollfondant is used to cover a whole cake, while Modellierfondant is used for modelling small figures to put on the cake. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The generic term for sugar-water pastes used to decorate food is [icing or frosting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icing_(food)).

*Rollfondant* sounds like ready-to-roll icing, but it could be [royal icing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_icing), which contains egg white.

*Modellierfondant* sounds like modelling paste. There are various recipes which use different additives to the core ingredients of sugar and water in order to obtain a suitable consistency and to dry without cracking.

Comment: The ingredients on the package don't list any egg white, so I think it would be ready-to-roll icing. I gather modelling paste is edible?

Comment: The modelling paste recipes I've seen are edible, but I don't know for sure that there aren't inedible ones out there.

Comment: Fondant is not royal icing, it is made from sugar syrup with a controlled amount of crystalization. It's its own type of icing.

Comment: What would be royal icing in german then?

Comment: royal icing = Eiweißglasur

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia differentiates between "rolled fondant" and "sculpting fondant": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fondant_icing

Answer (score 1):

"**Rollfondant**"  is "Rolled Fondant" or simply "Fondant"

I can't say for certain, but I suspect that "**Modellierfondant**" is also called "Fondant", but a different consistency (and we don't differentiate in English) ... or it's what they call "gumpaste", which is typically used for making flowers and other more delicate items.  There's also "modeling chocolate" (chocolate based), and of course Marzipan (which might be called "Almond Paste") for

Comment: a cliffhanger again :)